# How to get instagram id once user has authenticated (instagram-node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get the instagram id of a user once they have authenticated on my website. I have no problem authenticating since I can get an access_token when I log-in with my own account and I can use the following code **assuming I know the instaid of the user**

```
exports.renderUser = function(req, res){
 console.log("STARTING RENDERING");

 var userID = "280430135";

 api.user(userID, function(err, result, remaining, limit){
  if(err){
   console.log("current user " + err);
  }

  app.set('imgSource', result.profile_picture);
  app.use('/', routes);
  res.redirect('/');
 });
};
```

Am I supposed to get the instaid of the user from this authentication code?

```
exports.handleauth = function(req, res) {
  api.authorize_user(req.query.code, redirect_uri, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
     console.log(err.body);
     res.send("Didn't work");
    } else {
     console.log('Yay! Access token is ' + result.access_token);
     res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using instagram-node since I'm using express for my app.

Thanks!

Comment: It probably is in the `result` object. Did you try a  `console.log(result)`?

Comment: I added my answer below. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out a friend was able to answer my questions faster than I anticipated.

```
exports.handleauth
```

returns a json response with the user information in this format:

```
{
 "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
  "user": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "..."
  }
}
```

source: https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Therefore the instaid and other user information can be accessed by calling

```
result.user.id
result.user.full_name
```

etc...